# Pagelist in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Pagelist in my MVC application. I found it great!
When I try to search within the page, it shows how many pages is present for that current search but when I clicked the second page of the pagelist of that specific results, the total number of pages displayed is the original number of pages. 
Why so?
Here is my controller code snippet.

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter,int? page, string search, string searchBy)    
        var Users_info = from t in db.Users_info_vw
                              where t.is_active == true                                              select t;
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
         if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            switch (searchBy)
            {
                 case "user":
                    Users_info = Users_info.Where(x => x.Emp_FirstName.Contains(search)|| x.Emp_LastName.Contains(search));
                    break;
                default:
                    Users_info = Users_info.OrderByDescending(x => x.User_id);
                    break;
            }
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = search;
        int pageSize = 15;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        var returnMe = Users_info.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
        return View(returnMe);
}
```

In my view:

```
<div class="paging">
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", 
        new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
</div>
```

Can anyone help me for this one?

Comment: how do you call search? With ajax call or you reload whoule page? If you use Ajax call can be that you just don't reload pager silter values.

Comment: I'm using Html.BeginForm in searching.

Comment: I'm not seeing where `@Model.PageCount` is populated. Do you have that code? Also, I'm not sure exactly which property is incorrect. Can you be clearer?

Comment: @Charx, I'm using this reference: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

for pagelist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that you are not sending the correct parameter name in the controller in second page. For example you are using `search` as a parameter name in controller to search users in your DB, but you are putting this value in `currentFilter` parameter at the time the page list binding.

So either user `currentFilter` to filter your user records or send `search` parameter via page list, e.g. below:

**Solution 1 (In Controller)**

```
Users_info = Users_info.Where(x => x.Emp_FirstName.Contains(currentFilter)
                                || x.Emp_LastName.Contains(currentFilter));
```

and after that don't forget to assign ViewBag again e.g. `ViewBag.CurrentFilter = currentFilter;`

**Solution 2 (In View)**

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", 
        new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, search = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Hope this helps !!